# Why is this logical expression returning the global object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var root = (typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self) ||
        (typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global);
```

When I check it's value in the console it gives me the window object

```
console.log(root); // > Window
```

Comment: `self` is window in browser environment. Not clear what you expect

Comment: Why would you expect that expression to return something else than the global object? Is it about understanding the usage of the logical operators?

Comment: This *really* should have been written as `var root = (typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self) ? self : (typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global) ? global : undefined;`. (though the `undefined` could in fact be `false` or `global`)

Comment: I didn't write it, the backbone.js guys did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) is a property pointing to `window` itself. Therefore both checks will evaluate to true:

```
  typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self
```

And thanks to the definition of the and operator ....

> expr1 && expr2: Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

.... it will then return `self`, which is ... `window`:

```
 && self
```

Answer (score 2):

self is the window, when you "check" for && self, you get it.